# Comparing NSDate to [NSDate date] Fastest Way?

Tags: iphone, ios, date, sdk, nsdate

I have a core data table view and I am comparing dates. The method which I currently use is: `if ([todayDate compare: [NSDate date]]==NSOrderedAscending)` . This works perfectly but slow. I do not need to know the difference in time though. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you state more precisely what is slow? Is it `[NSDate date]` or the comparison? How have you measured the slowness? - If you need `[NSDate date]` in a loop with many elements you should compute it only once, perhaps that helps already.

Answer (score 1):

I really think, that NSDates method `isEqualToDate:` is what you are searching for. Seems to me to be the Apple-way to answer your question:

```
NSDate *date1 = ...;
NSDate *date2 = ...;

BOOL datesAreEqual = [date1 isEqualToDate:date2];
```

For more information visit https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help but it only tells me if the date is equal not smaller than or greater than. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: You should really read the "Comparing Dates" section in the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

In the case you need to know I would use `- (NSDate *)earlierDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate`

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to not actually create a new `NSDate` object but use the time interval for comparison. Don't know about the performance, but it might be worth a try.

```
if ([todayDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] > [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remember the current date or current timestamp in a local variable:

```
NSTimeInterval current = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

And use this value later for all your comparisons:

```
myTimestamp = [myDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]

if (myTimestamp == current) {
  return NSOrderedSame;
} else if (myTimestamp > current) {
  return NSOrderedDescending;
} else {
  return NSOrderedAscending;
}
```

Or a faster way, using C functions:

```
// Get the current calendar time as a time_t object.
time_t time ( time_t * timer );

// Return difference between two times
double difftime ( time_t time2, time_t time1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not measured it, but you may want to try:

```
NSTimeInterval i = [todayDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

where the result (`i`) may be positive or negative.

You might also try `CFDateCompare`.

Or you might want to consider another way to represent a point in time in your database -- such as a `CFTimeInterval` (a `double` representing the number of seconds from a common reference time).